# Does optional have any meaning for fields of message types in protobuf 3?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Starting from version 3.15 protobuf 3 officially reintroduced the `optional` keyword, which allows presence tracking for fields. Since presence tracking has already been available for message (non-scalar) fields, does adding `optional` make any difference for such fields?

Specifically, is there any difference (e.g., in terms of generated code) between

```
message Message {
   OtherMessage field = 1;
}
```

and

```
message Message {
   optional OtherMessage field = 1;
}
```

where OtherMessage is some defined protobuf message type.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can make a difference with some libraries.

Internally `protoc` will make a `oneof` out of the optional submessage field, just like it does with optional regular fields in proto3 syntax. Libraries that support proto3 optional fields will typically convert this back to regular submessage field, as they should have presence detection in any case.

However, old protobuf libraries (older than 2020) used with new protoc versions (3.15 and newer) can expose the automatically generated `oneof`. For example nanopb 0.3.x series does generate an unnecessary `oneof` when `optional` is specified for a submessage, while nanopb 0.4.x recognizes it as optional field.

Answer (score 1):

No, it makes no difference at all. All message-typed fields already support presence.

(It's *possible* that the presence of the keyword is detectable via the descriptor, but I wouldn't rely on it.)

I would personally recommend against specifying `optional` for message-typed fields, as it gives the *impression* that it's a meaningful thing to do, when it's not.